# Changing border color when a control is selected with c# on windows 8 app store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a gridview control with images and text with this xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,40,30,0" >
     <GridView x:Name="celebGridView" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0">
             <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
                 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
               </GridView.ItemsPanel>

               <GridView.Header>
                   <StackPanel Width="480" Margin="0,4,14,0">
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                          <TextBlock Text="Most Viewed Celebs" Foreground="black"                                       FontSize="25"/>
                           <Image Source="/images/Navigation-Right.png"  Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                         </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                  </GridView.Header>

                   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageBitmap}" />
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name_}" Foreground="Black"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        </GridView>
                    </Grid>
```

and i get this purple border around the selected items in the gridview below

[image: selected purple border color around image]

How can i override this behaviour, i need to change the color to a custom color (#fdeb01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using Expression Blend, note that Metro ListView selection color modification in XAML is also valid for GridViewItems so changing the following:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#fdeb01">     </SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#ffffff"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#fdeb01"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="#fdeb01"></SolidColorBrush>
```

will also affect the gridview.

Answer (score 4):

You could edit the ItemContainerStyle for the GridView. The easiest way is to use Blend and find the SelectedBorder element and change stroke brush to color you want.

[image: Open XAML with Blend and create/edit ItemContainerStyle]

[image: Look for SelectedBorder element]

[image: Change stroke brush to a custom color]

[image: And you should see something like this]